# What is DefaultFileSystem in the Java 8 File.java source code?

Tags: java

Line 156 in the [Java 8 File.java source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/File.java) is

```
private static final FileSystem fs = DefaultFileSystem.getFileSystem();
```

This is the only occurrence of DefaultFileSystem on the page.  By the capitalization, I guessed that it would be the name of a class, but "DefaultFileSystem" does not show up on the [Java 8 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) in the list of all classes.  So what is DefaultFileSystem referring to?

Comment: A package-private class, presumably, not part of the public API.  The "list of all classes" is only the list of _public_ classes.

Comment: on my linux operating system I have installed jdk 1.8. when I navigate `DefaultFileSystem` class in my ide (eclipse) it is like `package java.io;

/**
 *
 * @since 1.8
 */
class DefaultFileSystem {

    /**
     * Return the FileSystem object for Unix-based platform.
     */
    public static FileSystem getFileSystem() {
        return new UnixFileSystem();
    }
}`